# How to create a triple-join table with Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, model

Using Django's built in models, how would one create a triple-join between three models.

For example:

- Users, Roles, and Events are the models.
- Users have many Roles, and Roles many Users.  (ManyToMany)
- Events have many Users, and Users many Events. (ManyToMany)
- But for any given Event, any User may have only one Role.

How can this be represented in the model?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**zacherates** writes:

> I'd model Role as an association class between Users and Roles (...)

I'd also reccomed this solution, but you can also make use of some syntactical sugar provided by Django: [ManyToMany relation with extra fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Role')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Role(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: This is quite new in Django (since 1.0).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend just creating an entirely separate model for this.

```
class Assignment(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    role = ForeignKey(Role)
    event = ForeignKey(Event)
```

This lets you do all the usual model stuff, such as

```
user.assignment_set.filter(role__name="Chaperon")
role.assignment_set.filter(event__name="Silly Walkathon")
```

The only thing left is to enforce your one-role-per-user-per-event restriction.  You can do this in the Assignment class by either overriding the save method (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) or using signals (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)

Comment: Is not `unique_together = ('user', 'event')` enough for one role per user per event constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I'd model Role as an association class between Users and Roles, thus,

```
class User(models.Model):
     ...

class Event(models.Model):
     ...

class Role(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

And enforce the one role per user per event in either a manager or SQL constraints.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to find a faster three-table join for my own Django models, I came across this question.  By default, Django 1.1 uses INNER JOINs which can be slow on InnoDB.  For a query like:

```
def event_users(event_name):
    return User.objects.filter(roles__events__name=event_name)
```

this might create the following SQL:

```
SELECT `user`.`id`, `user`.`name` FROM `user` INNER JOIN `roles` ON (`user`.`id` = `roles`.`user_id`) INNER JOIN `event` ON (`roles`.`event_id` = `event`.`id`) WHERE `event`.`name` = "event_name"
```

The INNER JOINs can be very slow compared with LEFT JOINs.  An even faster query can be found under gimg1's answer: [Mysql query to join three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257433/mysql-query-to-join-three-tables#10257569)

```
SELECT `user`.`id`, `user`.`name` FROM `user`, `roles`, `event` WHERE `user`.`id` = `roles`.`user_id` AND `roles`.`event_id` = `event`.`id` AND `event`.`name` = "event_name"
```

However, you will need to use a custom SQL query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

In this case, it would look something like:

```
from django.db import connection
def event_users(event_name):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select U.name from user U, roles R, event E' \
                   ' where U.id=R.user_id and R.event_id=E.id and E.name="%s"' % event_name)
    return [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```