# How to describe m2m triple-join table in model (Django)

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, model, many-to-many

My question is pretty much the same [as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945), except that ALL relationships should be many-to-many.

I have the following classes in my models.py (somewhat simplified):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # Extending the built in User model  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)  
    birthday = models.DateField()

class Media(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

What I want is a junction table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `media_roles` (
    `media_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `profile_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `role_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL
)
```

- John Doe - Director, Writer, Producer
- Jane Doe - Executive Producer
- ...

This is what I've used so far:

```
class MediaRole(models.Model):
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
```

But isn't there any better way of doing this, not involving the creation of a separate class in the model?

Comment: This is the standard solution.  What do you think is wrong with it?  Please detail the things you don't like about this.

Comment: It's not that I think there's something wrong with it. I just thought there'd be another way which would give me some free functionality like a standard ManyToManyField would.

Comment: It's **not** a simple many-to-many.  It's a rare exceptional case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about separating the two m2m relationships?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    medias = models.ManyToManyField(Media, related_name='profiles')
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, related_name='profiles')
```

In this way Django create two association tables for you, and you can utilize the convenient related fields like this:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=someone)
print profile.medias.all()
print profile.roles.all()
```

Comment: How would that make it possible to assign multiple Roles per Profile per Media upload? I'm confused

Comment: @Saosin, it sounds like you want a m2m relationship between `Profile` and `Media`, and for each of these relationship there are many `Roles`. If so, you may try creating an association table of `Profile` and `Media`, and then make `roles` a foreignkey.

Comment: Using an intermediate model with 'through' like this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships? Since there may only be two foreign keys in it - one pointing to the source model and the other to target that wouldn't work. Or am I misunderstanding the documentation?