# Mysql query to join three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am using this query:

```
SELECT a.sales_id, d.bus_title, a.cat_id
FROM tbl_sales a
INNER JOIN tb_category b ON a.cat_id = b.cat_id
INNER JOIN tbl_business d ON d.bus_id = a.bus_id
```

which produces this result:

```
sales_id  | bus_title      |cat_id
----------|----------------|------------
 1        | Business 1     | 6  
 2        | Business 12    | 12
 3        | Business 123   | 25
```

I changed the field cat_id into a new table named `tb_sales_category` which contains the fields `sales_category_id`, `sales_id`, `cat_id`. How can I write the new query by joining this table too to, get the same result as above?

I am kind of new to databases, need help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.sales_id, d.bus_title, s.cat_id
FROM tbl_sales a
INNER JOIN tb_sales_category s ON a.sales_id = s.sales_id
INNER JOIN tbl_business      d ON a.bus_id   = d.bus_id
INNER JOIN tb_category       b ON s.cat_id   = b.cat_id
```

The idea is fairly simple, the first field in your new table `tb_sales_category` which is `sales_category_id` is working as a *surrogate key*, it has nothing to do with the relations between the two other tables. Then we come to the other two fields which are `sales_id`, `cat_id`, these what you should map to the other two sides of the relations.

You can't `Join tb_category b ON a.cat_id = b.cat_id` on the new schema becouse we no longer have `a.cat_id`, and here comes the new table `tb_sales_category` role, by inserting it with two binding sides, one with `INNER JOIN tb_category b ON s.cat_id = b.cat_id` and the other with `INNER JOIN tb_sales_category s ON a.sales_id = s.sales_id` we should be done.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: also thanks for the explanation, this will help me in my self learning process

Answer (score 5):

I am not a great fan of inner joins so try this:

```
SELECT a.sales_id, a.cat_id, c.bus_title
FROM tb_sales_category a, tb_sales b, tbl_business c
WHERE a.sales_id = b.sales_id
AND b.bus_id = c.bus_id
```

Comment: Why on earth don't you like INNER JOINs?

Comment: @gimg1 Thanks, that serves the purpose