# SQL music playlist database queries from design

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

Im trying to implement this database design. I am new to mysql and do not really understand how to connect everything so i am trying to break every query down to pieces..

Database looks like

Songs:

```
id title length artist_id
```

Artists:

```
id name
```

Playlists:

```
id title user_id
```

Playlists_Songs:

```
playlist_id song_id
```

Users:

```
id name email
```

Query - 
get the users playlistname and the playlist id

```
SELECT users.id,users.name,playlists.playlistname,playlists.id 
FROM users, playlists
WHERE users.user_id = playlists.users_id

outputs :
user_id | user_username | playlistname | id
```

How do i use the id from the output to continue query "deeper" to get the playlist_songs ?

Sorry for confusion question, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Please use the more useful explicit joins rather than implicit(comma) joins. And do google how to join 3 tables = there's lots out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query to join three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257433/mysql-query-to-join-three-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect tables, you can use `Joins`. If you want to get data from `playlist_songs`, you can use query like

```
SELECT users.id,users.name,playlists.playlistname,playlists.id, playlist_songs.song_id FROM users 
        inner join playlists on users.user_id = playlists.users_id
        inner join playlist_songs on playlist_songs.playlist_id = playlists.id
WHERE users.user_id = <user_id_of_user>
```

You can join `songs` table with `playlist_songs` and then `artists` table with `songs`.

Comment: Thank you!! Do i do the joins for the songs with playlist_songs in the same query ?

Comment: Yes you can join in same query and include the columns that you need from that tables in select statement.

Comment: Thank you again, i have now accomplished what i wanted!